# Converter meu JSON para Excel

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, npm

Preci*so de uma biblioteca que receba a query e quando eu aperte determinado botão exporte o resultado em arquivo excel, detalhe é que estou utilizando chart (gráfico) do google e pretendo também colocar no documento um gráfico parecido. junto com uma tabela que será o resultado da query.

**Exemplo:**

```
[
{"cod_bolsa":"5","nome_projeto":"3D Printing","ano_vigencia_inicial":"2017","ano_vigencia_final":"2017","departamento":"Eletr\u00f4nica","orientador":"EXEMPLO1","tipo_bolsa":"PIBIC CNPq"},
{"cod_bolsa":"9","nome_projeto":"3D Printing","ano_vigencia_inicial":"2017","ano_vigencia_final":"2017","departamento":"Ensino","orientador":"EXEMPLO2","tipo_bolsa":"PIBIC Fund. Arauc\u00e1ria"},
{"cod_bolsa":"11","nome_projeto":"An\u00e1lise inorg\u00e2nica de amostras de alimentos e ambientais por espectrometria de absor\u00e7\u00e3o at\u00f4mica","ano_vigencia_inicial":"2017","ano_vigencia_final":"2017","departamento":"Alimentos","orientador":"EXEMPLO4","tipo_bolsa":"PIBIC Fund. Arauc\u00e1ria"},
{"cod_bolsa":"12","nome_projeto":"An\u00e1lise inorg\u00e2nica de amostras de alimentos e ambientais por espectrometria de absor\u00e7\u00e3o at\u00f4mica","ano_vigencia_inicial":"2017","ano_vigencia_final":"2017","departamento":"Eletr\u00f4nica","orientador":"EXEMPLO5","tipo_bolsa":"PIBIC Fund. Arauc\u00e1ria"}
]
```

Comment: Veja se isso resolve o seu problema: https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-as-json

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso fazer o oposto, que é json para excel e não excel para json, e pelo que vi no na documentação ele só produz o json a partir do arquivo excel.

Comment: Poderia passar um exemplo de um JSON que voce quer transformar ?

Comment: vou colocar na pergunta, porque aqui não cabe